# What is the sum of values that $a$ can take?

Tags: absolute-value

$x$ and $y$ are negative integers.

$y+x = -5$

$\left\lvert x-y \right\rvert + a \cdot \left\lvert y-x \right\rvert = 12$

- What is the sum of values that $a$ can take?

I know that

$\left\lvert y-x \right\rvert = \left\lvert x-y \right\rvert$

Comment: Well, if $x,y$ are negative integers that sum to $-5$ there really aren't a lot of things to try, are there?

Comment: @lulu I thought like that :) By the way, $x = -2$ or $y = -3$. Perhaps $x = -3$ or $y = -2$

Comment: No...you can have $\{x,y\}=\{-4,-1\}$ as well.

Comment: @lulu Exactly, however what will we do then? There are three combinations and more.

Comment: Not following.  You have all four possible solutions.  Just solve for $a$ in each case and sum.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I don't understand where you are stuck. Let's take $(x,y)=(-2,-3)$.  Then we have $(1-a)\times |x-y|=(1-a)\times 1=(1-a)=12\implies a=-11$.  That's one value of  $a$.  Just get the others and add them up.

Comment: @lulu Why is it $1-a$?

Comment: It's not, it is $1+a$ I misread.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, we have 
$$|x-y| + a|x-y| = 12 \implies (a+1)|x-y| = 12$$
after factoring out $|x-y|$,
which means that, after doing some algebra,
$$a=\dfrac{12}{|x-y|}-1\text{.}$$
Now, given that $x, y$ are negative integers which sum to $-5$, you could have
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
x & y  & |x-y|\\
\hline
-1 & -4 & 3 \\
-2 & -3 & 1\\
-3 & -2 & 1\\
-4 & -1 & 0\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
Assuming that $x$ and $y$ are distinct (you can't divide by $0$), you may plug in $3, 1$, and $1$ into the formula for $a$ above to obtain its possible values.

Answer (score 0):

in the Case of $$x\geq y$$ we have to solve
$$(x-y)(a+1)=12$$ and $$x+y=-5$$
in the Case of $$x<y$$ we have to solve $$(-x+y)(a+1)=12$$ and $$x+y=-5$$
Can you proceed?
we find $$a=3,x=-4,y=-1$$ or $$a=3,x=-1,y=-4$$ or $$a=11,x=-3,y=-2$$ or $$a=11,x=-2,y=-3$$
we Can also use that $$x-y=\frac{12}{a+1}$$ or $$-x+y=\frac{12}{a+1}$$

Comment: I didn't get it.

Comment: i have added the Solutions!

Comment: Why did we use $a+1$?